# JOIN 2 Tables MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have tables:

`a`

```
id, title, description
1,  test ,  test
2,  test ,  test
```

`b`

```
id, a_id, vw
 1,    2,  4
```

And i want to create query to create this

**ID** from a, **SUM(vw)** from b, but when b **doesn't** have **a_id** must display vw **0**.

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a left outer join, like so:

```sql
select a.id, sum(ifnull(b.vw, 0)) 
  from a
  left outer join b on a.id = b.a_id
  group by a.id
```

If you want to filter B, remember that you have a left outer join, so, you have two choices, you put a filter on the `on` of the left outer join or you put it on the where it a isnull

First option:

```sql
select a.id, sum(ifnull(b.vw, 0)) 
  from a
  left outer join b on a.id = b.a_id and b.a_id = {id_user}
  group by a.id
```

Second option:

```sql
select a.id, sum(ifnull(b.vw, 0)) 
  from a
    left outer join b on a.id = b.a_id
  where isnull(b.a_id) = 1 or b.a_id = {id_user}
  group by a.id
```

Comment: it display only one record :/ with vw from all(?)

Comment: I've forgot the group by clause! :)

Comment: Great but when b dont have record with a_id from a it doesnt display 0

Comment: You know what i mean? Sorry for my english.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. Just setup a database and rerun the query and all was ok. Two records one with zero and another with the sum of dummy values

Comment: If b doesnt have any record with some a_id, this a doesnt display

Comment: @JanuszJanusz, The left outer join garantees that all the records from `a` are returned and if the match `a.in = b.a_id` doesn't match `null` is returned instead of `b`. Consider doing just `Select a.id, b.id, b.a_id from ...` and see the output. If this still goes on maybe we should go to the chat so I can help you better.

Comment: In my orginal query i have WHERE b.id_user = {id_user} statement maybe this help

Comment: @JanuszJanusz I've edited with your new requirement. Sometimes is just easy to show the full original code! :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(IF(b.a_id IS NULL, 0,b.vw))
FROM a,b
WHERE a.id = b.a_id
```